# press 'done' button on mobile keyboard is not trigger close in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div that use contenteditable = "true", when i use mobile device like iphone and click this div (focus this div), keyboard will open.
But when I click "done" button on keyboard (not return/enter), the keyboard can't close.
How can I close the keyboard when I click "done" button. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```js
document.getElementById('send-msg-content').addEventListener("keypress", function( event ) {
  alert('keypress');
}, true);

document.getElementById('send-msg-content').addEventListener("keydown", function( event ) {
  alert('keydown');
}, true);

document.getElementById('send-msg-content').addEventListener("keyup", function( event ) {
  alert('keyup');
}, true);
```

```css
.send-msg-content{
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
    border:1px solid blue;
    resize: none;
}

.send-msg-content:empty:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #aaa;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    line-height: 1em;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div oncontextmenu="return false;" contenteditable="true" placeholder="talk something" class="send-msg-content" id="send-msg-content" inputmode="text"></div>
```

This gif file is my operation situation:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this `? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570362/hiding-soft-keyboards-on-mobile-devices-when-using-contenteditable-divs

Comment: Yes, I have use javascript setting my div has "keypress", "keyup", "keydown" events, but when i click "done" button，all events can't trigger

Comment: can you please add JS? so we can understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry, I have add JS, if use mobile keyboard and press 'done' button on keyboard, nothing will happened.
If i can capture press 'done' button event, then I can close keyboard that use document.getElementById('send-msg-content').blur()