# How to highlight a text selection using javascript in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

Under iOS4 I could highlight a text range using document.execCommand as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223682/change-css-of-selected-text-using-javascript). Under iOS6 turning on the design mode always brings up the keyboard. The only way to close the keyboard seem to be focusing a inputbox and the blurring it as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949222/closing-keyboard-on-ipad-in-div-contenteditable?lq=1). Sadly this approach isn't fast enough so the keyboard will pop up for a short time.

Is there any other approach to highlighting text in mobile Safari or a way to hide the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution: the [CSS Class Applier Module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) from rangy.